# Subir archivos a un servidor con c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio con C#, la cual sube archivos a un servidor, en este caso sería mi servidor local xampp, dentro del servidor tengo creado un proyecto en el cual se almacenaran los archivos subidos a través de la aplicación realizada con C#, ojo no es aplicación asp es aplicación de escritorio, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
string url = "";
string destino = "";

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  destino = Path.Combine(@"\\127.0.0.1\Sessiones\archivos{0}", Path.GetFileName(url));
  File.Copy(url, destino);
  MessageBox.Show("Imagen guardada correctamente");
}

private void btnExaminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

  openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "'c:\'";
  openFileDialog.Filter = "jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|png (*.png)|*.png|gif (*.gif)|*.gif";

  if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     url = openFileDialog.FileName;
     pbImagen.ImageLocation = url;
     pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
  }
}
```

El problema es que me marca esta excepción y no sube el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modifique el código y ahora quedo así:

```
string url = "";

.....

private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int resultado = SubirArchivo();

    if (resultado == 1)
        MessageBox.Show("Archivo subido correctamente");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un problema al subir el archivo");
}

private int SubirArchivo()
{
    try
    {
      FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/Sessiones/archivos/" + Path.GetFileName(url));
      request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
      request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "password");
      request.UsePassive = true;
      request.UseBinary = true;
      request.KeepAlive = true;
      FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(url);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
      stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      stream.Close();
      Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
      reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      reqStream.Flush();
      reqStream.Close();
      return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return 0;
    }
}

private void btnExaminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "'c:\'";
    openFileDialog.Filter = "jpg (*.jpg)|*.jpg|png (*.png)|*.png|gif (*.gif)|*.gif";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        url = openFileDialog.FileName;
        pbImagen.ImageLocation = url;
        pbImagen.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
```

El problema sigue ahora me marca:

> "No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto"

En usuario le puse el usuario que uso para conectar al servidor de bases de datos
y en password le puse la contraseña del usuario que se conecta al servidor de bases de datos. Estoy bien ahí o que tengo que poner esos datos?? O por donde va el problema??

Ya hice que mi servidor xampp sea ftp, utilizo la aplicación de FileZilla y todo bien transfiere archivos correctamente pero intento usar mi aplicación c# y no quiere me marca error 550 error de acceso, por que C# no quiere hacer lo que le estoy pidiendo??

Comment: Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras No lo sube

Comment: Por que usas un path con `127.0.0.1` en lugar de usar la ruta local?  Por otro lado...que es `url`?

Comment: @Pikoh para acceder al servidor local ó como lo podría acceder??

Comment: Me parece que el error dice que no encuentra la ruta que especificaste para guardar el archivo, usa el debug para ver cómo está creándola. Por otro lado, supongo que Pikoh se refiere a que, si usas '127.0.0.1', o usas 'localhost', la apliación sólo subirá archivos cuando la ejecutes en el servidor. Al menos eso entiendo...

Comment: con File copy solo guardas archivos en carpetas  dentro de tu pc o alguna carpeta "compartida" dentro de tu red local, en tucaso solo escribe la ip de tu pc (192.168....), si buscas un servidor ip externo entonces debes enviarlo por otro metodo ejemplo ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví después de tanto explico:

Primero tuve que hacer que mi servidor xampp fuera sevidor ftp:

Este es el tutorial de como hacerlo: [Configuración del Servidor FTP en XAMPP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Krh9NHz_yN8)

Una vez que relice todo lo que viene ahí, fue cambiar mi código así:

```
private int SubirArchivo()
{
    try
    {
      FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://127.0.0.1/archivos/imagen.jpg");
      request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
      request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "password");
      request.UsePassive = true;
      request.UseBinary = true;
      request.KeepAlive = true;
      FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(url);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
      stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      stream.Close();
      Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
      reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      reqStream.Flush();
      reqStream.Close();
      return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return 0;
    }
}
```