# Subir documento excel (asp.net) y enviar la info al servidor y guardarlo en una base de datos

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, excel

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:
¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores de un `Excel` cargado en un `<input type="file">` en una lista de objetos en `C#` `.net` ya que deseo actualizar la información cargada del `Excel` a la base de datos en base a un código a multiples registros.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>

<body>
   <input type="file">
</body>

</html>
```

Esta es la imagen del excel y en base de datos tiene esas mismas columnas pero quiero hacer una actualización de esos tres registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que debes ir por partes. Primero céntrate en subir el archivo y guardarlo en el servidor, luego ya te pelearás con abrir en el servidor el Excel y leerlo. Para subir al servidor el archivo, esta [pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261159/subir-archivos-a-un-servidor-con-c) te puede ayudar.

Comment: Que tantos códigos estarías cargando desde el excel?

Comment: 10 a 20 registros en base a un codigo diferente

Comment: No entiendo esto "registros en base a un código diferente", esto significa que cada código es diferente o que? Puedes publicar como se ve el excel que debes cargar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atendiendo a tu comentario, de que no es una carga de trabajo tan pesada el leer el excel yo haría algo como esto:

1. Leer y Cargar el excel, colocando la lista de valores en un input  con un formato establecido.
2. hacer un parse del input en el code behind, para luego almacenarlo o actualizarlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Upload() {

            debugger;
            //Reference the FileUpload element.
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");

            //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
            if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    //For Browsers other than IE.
                    if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    } else {
                        //For IE Browser.
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var data = "";
                            var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                                data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                            }
                            ProcessExcel(data);
                        };
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
            }
        };

         function ProcessExcel(data) {         
            //Read the Excel File data.
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });

            //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
            var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
            //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
            var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
            var rowsArray = Array(excelRows.length);


            var empleados = {};

            // ...and then:
            empleados = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
                var temp_item = excelRows[i];

                // Maybe, here make something like:
                // temp_item.name = 'some value'

                empleados.push({
                    "Id_empleado": excelRows[i].Id_empleado,
                    "Nombre": excelRows[i].Nombre,
                    "Salario": excelRows[i].Salario
                });
            }        
        };
        
       function onUpdate(data) {
   
    ObjUpdate = data
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:PUERTO/RegistroEmpleados.aspx/ActualizarEmpleado",
            data: JSON.stringify(ObjUpdate),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) 
   {
                var data = JSON.parse(response.d);

                if (data.Mensaje === "success") {
                    $('.btn-primary').show();

                    $("#mensaje").removeClass("alert-danger");                   
                }
                else {
                    $("#mensaje").removeClass("alert-success");                   
                }                
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
}
       
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
            <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
            <input type="text" id="ListaCodigos" />
            <hr />
            <div id="dvExcel"></div>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


---esto va en el codebehind c#-----

public static string ActualizarEmpleado(Update ObjUpdate)
{
 string json = String.Empty;
 int count = 0;
 try
 {
        
 }
 catch (Exception  ex) 
 {
  response.Mensaje = "Error";
  response.DetalleError = ex.Message;
  json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
  return json;
 }


 response.Mensaje = "success"; 
 json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
 return json;
}
```

Ademas debes crear un metodo similar a este para recibir el json en el codebehind:

Comment: como lo almacenaría los datos del excel en un json para luego pasarlos como una lista de datos al controlador en .net ya que tendría que realizar el update múltiple hacia los registros que coinciden con la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Y si fuera mayor cantidad de datos se caería este método?

Comment: La repuesta sugerida me pareció algo apropiado para lo que expusiste (una carga liviana de trabajo de 10 a 20 registros).Hay muchos enfoques que podrían abordarse para solucionar esto, pero, eso dependerá de 1)La carga de trabajo 2)La cantidad de usuario que harían este proceso 3)La arquitectura de todo el sistema, es decir redes, servidores, etc. Ahora bien, personalmente continuaría con el enfoque que ya abordamos si la carga de trabajo  no pasara de ese numero de registros (10 o 20 ).

Comment: Si fuera mas pensaría en otro enfoque, pero desconozco el contexto de lo que intentas resolver.

Comment: La funcionalidad que deseo hacer es actualizar los datos de la tabla empleados de mi base de datos por la data que tiene mi excel, es por ello que pedía leer los datos del excel y tenerlo en un json y pasarlo a mi controlador y para luego después recorrerlo e ir pasandole los datos a mi store procedure que actualizará mi base de datos.

Comment: Si, eso lo dejaste claro desde el principio, pero se necesita mas contexto : 1)La carga de trabajo 2)La cantidad de usuario que harían este proceso 3)La arquitectura de todo el, .. etc, para decidir si este es el mejor enfoque, si estas dudando de la cantidad de registros que necesitas actualizar mediante este proceso, es mejor considerar otro enfoque, pero para analizar otro enfoque...se necesita saber ese contexto.

Comment: La cantidad de registros a actualizar del excel va a variar, Los usuarios que harían ese proceso solo es uno, y la arquitectura usada es capas(Capa Entidad= clases,Capa Datos= métodos,capa Negocio= que referencia capa datos, controlador ), y las acciones de los botones lo trabajo con jquery.

Comment: Usas PHP, HTML,aspx?  usas ajax para la comunicación ?

Comment: solo C# .net, jquery, ajax

Comment: Edite la respuesta para brindarte una guía.